# Can't convert iso-8859-1 to utf-8

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash

I tried to convert the file and failed. There you can see al my actions:

```
david@david-ThinkPad-E480:/$ locale charmap
UTF-8

david@david-ThinkPad-E480:/$ file -bi posmotret.txt
text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1

david@david-ThinkPad-E480:/$ iconv -f iso-8859-1 -t UTF-8 posmotret.txt 

ëþáèòü íåëüçÿ ðàññòàòüñÿ - 6
ñåìüÿ ïî áûñòðîìó - 6
òèì òàëëåð èëè ïðîäàííûé ñìåõ - 6
âëàñòü - 6
```

This is an unfamiliar language even for me :)

Comment: @Kamil Maciorowski thanks for trying, but no, the output is only a few symbols

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file is not in iso-8859-1 but in cp1251.

```
$ iconv -f cp1251 -t utf8 posmotret.txt
любить нельзя расстаться - 6
семья по быстрому - 6
тим таллер или проданный смех - 6
власть - 6
```

Comment: @choroda how you figured out it, so `file` has lied to me ? :)

Comment: @salius A file's types and character sets are often ambiguous.  Even in the best of times, `file` is only offering a likely guess.

Comment: `file` can only guess, all the 8-bit encodings are similar to each other. I've seen mojibake or Кракозябры many times, so I can recognise some scripts.